# Are $X$ and $Y$ necessarily normal if the the sum $Z=X+Y$ is normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

Of course, asking the question the other way round is straightforward to answer as via the convolution we find that the sum of two normal distributed variables is again normal.

But however, is it possible that $X$ and $Y$ follow different distributions but the sum is again normal?

Comment: Suppose $Y = -X$.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Why does this give me that the sum is normal again? You mean $Y$ follows an arbitrary distribution and therefore $Y+X=0$? But this sum is not really normal?

Comment: 0 is not normalizable. I don't think it can be considered "normal distribution"

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part. Suppose in fact that $Y = Z - X$, where $Z$ is a known normal distribution, and $X$ is anything. Or even simpler, consider $X = 0$ (which isn't normal) and $Y$ to be a normal distribution, then $X + Y = Y$ is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If X and Y are independent, then the result follows from Cramer's Theorem.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem) is a link. Note the requirement of independence here.

In the non-independence case, if $Y=Z-X$, where $Z$ is normal, and $X$ has any distribution also works.